# How to show sales order details in magento from one store to another magento store

Tags: magento-1.9

i have four Magento site. example

1. www.abc.com
2. www.cde.com
3. www.ads.com
4. www.example.com

now i want to show all sales order from all four site to new in magento site  example www.xyz.com. is it possible if yes then how.

Comment: Are these stores part of the same Magento installation?

Comment: version is same but all are having  there separate  Fronted and back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Or at least not from within Magento, as you state that the stores are not part of the same Magento installation.

Of course you could however retrieve the orders via the (external) Magento API and then display them on your other site.